# google sign in doesn't work in release mode?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-signin, release

my app is made with flutter.
I am using **firebase** to **google sign in** option. And I added **SHA keys** when I am on debug mode.
so, can I know **SHA key** is depends on the debug mode & release mode?

And also can I know how I am see/monitor release mode activities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, firebase requires a different fingerprint for release mode, please generate keys using this command,

```sh
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}

example:

keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\MG\Desktop\test.jks -alias test
```

To monitor events, you can integrate Firebase Crashlytics into your project.

to temporarily debug your app in release mode run

```sh
flutter run --release
```

Comment: solution summary..........go to your 'flutter_project/android' using terminal & then './gradlew signingReport' paste this to see the keys.
when you are didn't sign your app with release mode, you cannot get the release SHA key, to get the release mode SHA key to sign your app & in 'android/app/build.gradle' file signinconfig as 'signingConfigs.release'